# Is it possible allow the user to filter all the data he wants?

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am completely new using datastore and I have a doubt related to filters.

Here is my entity defined in java-objectify:

```
@Entity
public class Element {


    @Id
    private long id;

    @Index
    private String item1;

    @Index
    private Integer item2;

    //(...) 3-39 items

    @Index
    private String item40;


}
```

I want the user be able to filter 'kinds' of this 'entity' using any type of filter combination.

For example:

```
query = query.filter("item1 =", "Tokyo").filter("item25 <", 10).filter("item3 >" , 0);
```

To use this filter, I need to create index such as the following:

```
<datastore-index kind="Conference" ancestor="false"
    source="auto">
    <property name="item1" direction="asc" />
    <property name="item25" direction="asc" />
    <property name="item3" direction="asc" />       
</datastore-index>
```

So to allow all combinations of filters with 40 items would have to create a 
incredibly large number of indexes

My questions are:

Does Google DataStore is designed for these types of queries?

Is there any other way to let the user freedom in the filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not like you're thinking, flexible filtering is possible thanks to the [zigzag merge join algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection), but that only covers equality filters, for inequality and ordering you'll need composite indexes (that cap at 200), and even then [inequality filters are limited to at most one property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries).

So definitively not the right use for this kind of database, what you could do is either think of more task-oriented search filters (like in the example of the first article, which is a must read), or design your query interface around the limitations and only offer equality filters, single property sorting (because each property would require a new composite index and you don't want to run out), and only one space for inequality (just be sure to fully understand the restrictions outlined in the second article).